# Excel countif comma separated criter

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have an excel spreadsheet with a project column and columns for each month of the year.  On a different tab on the same spreadsheet, tab name = JIRA.  For example:

**Main Tab:**

```
Project(Column L)     hours
P1
P2
```

**JIRA tab**

```
Project (col B)    Jan hours (Col J) FEB hours (Col K)<br>
P1                 14                10<br>
P2                 15                10<br>
P3                 5                 15<br>
P4                 32                5<br>
P5                 20                22<br>
P6                 25                15<br>
```

If I use the following formula in the hours column of the main tab in the Feb column, I can get the hours to populated correctly:

```
=SUMIF(JIRA!$B:$B,L4,JIRA!$J:$J)<br>
```

My Problem:
I want to put multiple project number on the same column on the main tab separated by a comma:

**Main Tab:**

```
Project(Column L)     hours<br>
P1<br>
P2<br>
P1,P2<br>
P3,P4,P5<br>
```

How do I get the sumif formula to recognize multiple project names and search for each project summing the total?  Based on the above, after plugging in the correct formula, I want to see:

**Main Tab:**

```
Project(Column L)     Jan hours    FEb hours<br>
P1<br>                  14            10
P2<br>                  15            10
P1,P2<br>               29            20
P3,P4,P5<br>            57            42
```

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
frank

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND($A$2:$A$10&",";D2&","))*$B$2:$B$10)
```

In my example names(P1,P2...etc) are in A2:A10, B2:B10 contains the values to sum and D2 is the names your looking for.

Depending on your Regional Settings you may need to replace ";" by ","